# python module doesn't run after installation

Tags: python

I tried to install a module and successfully do so. But after installing it and seeing it on the pip list, for some reason I cannot run it. Every time I execute the py file a notepad pops up. Here is my setup.py:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'My Name',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it',
    'author_email': 'My email',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['try2'],
    'scripts': ['bin/try2.py'],
    'name': 'try2' }

setup(**config)
```

Comment: If you installed it, setup.py should have been run.

Comment: I installed it using the following code: python setup.py install